# Edittext addTextChangedListener is crashing

Tags: android, crash, android-edittext

My App is crashing when I start this activity. I have an edit text defined in my layout and I instantiate inside onCreate of my activity. I am creating listeners for my Edittext.

```
mTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
mTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

mTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Can you post the logcat output so we can see the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not because of EditText. It was due to some other problem that I found using LogCat. Thanks for your advise to make use of LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

Without the stack trace it is hard to tell what the problem is. If I had to guess I would say you are getting a NullPointerException when you call mTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);. This would be caused by the findViewById retuning null because it couldn't find any view with the given id in your activity. Have you called [setContentView(int layoutId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29) before the code you have posted? Also if you have called setContentView are you sure that the layout you are inflating in that call actually contains an EditText widget with and id of edit_text?